# The Fn key wont work on Toshiba satellite L735?

Tags: keyboard-layout, brightness

The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key wont work on my Toshiba satellite L735 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but: Did it work with Windows OS?

Comment: i wnat correct driver for toshiba L735 becous before my laptop when press FN key then show f1 f2 f3 this key now stop ready mean dont show

Answer (score 1):

I have a Toshiba Satellite L510 with Ubuntu 12.04, I fixed this issue installing fnfx-client. And after installed, it worked automatically!!!

```
sudo apt-get install fnfx-client
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=X
```

Where x is 0-99, and 0 turns the display off.  I have a Toshiba Satellite t135-S1309 and this was the only command I ever found to change the brightness.  It's possible to set it up to bind to the keys or to set a brightness on boot, but I was never bothered by it to that degree.  Not a perfect fix but it will change your brightness.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my Toshiba R830. What worked for me was the following changes to Grub:

Press Alt + F2 and type `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`

Find the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and modify it to one of the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

or

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"`

or

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"` (this is what worked for me but others had success with the former)

Save and close gedit.

Open a terminal (ctrl + alt + T) and type sudo update-grub. Reboot your pc after each try.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Toshiba

i installed **fnfxd** package search *synaptic Package Manger* for it

it solved my problem

hope it helps u too

please note the difference between ***fnfx*** and ***fnfxd*** the latest one solved my problem