# Toshiba satellite L300 Xubuntu 12.04 : no brightness control

Tags: xubuntu, brightness, toshiba-satellite

Since my new xubuntu installation (after the previous LTS) I lost control over the brightness - there used to be a brightness adjustment applet on the top panel, and now it's gone. I tried to restore Fn keys functionality, or changing the grub, but none of

[The Fn key wont work on Toshiba satellite L735?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137221/the-fn-key-wont-work-on-toshiba-satellite-l735)

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

worked for me (I did remember to do sudo update-grub before rebooting)

The fnfx client also did not change anything, when I try to run it `fnfx` it gives me an error:

```
FnFX Client v0.3 (c) 2003, 2004 Timo Hoenig <thoenig@nouse.net>

fatal error: Could not open "/home/chris/.fnfxrc". Please make sure that the default     config is accessible.
```

This command `sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=X`   does not work for me neither.

I cannot follow this [Fn keys for Brightness not working on Toshiba Satellite L755](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148365/fn-keys-for-brightness-not-working-on-toshiba-satellite-l755) suggestion to edit BIOS settings (which are not defined in that post) - does anyone know which settings could be changed in BIOS, and how ?

I run out of possibilities. Any other suggestions that could perhaps enable me to control the brightness of my display?  Pointing me in a good direction would be really helpful.

Thank you so much,

Chris

Comment: Take a look at my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/303088/screen-brightness-reduction-software/303093#303093), see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Chris, I found this in a previous similar question to your...check it out to see if it helps you and/or guides you in the right path...

[How can I adjust brightness settings when I am on battery?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79730/how-can-i-adjust-brightness-settings-when-i-am-on-battery)

Good luck,

Luis

Comment: Hi! 

Using `xgamma -gamma 0.8` (to reduce the brightness - 1 is default) does not change the brightness but gamma correction, which alters colours, and does not look well for very low values of gammma, so this is not a good solution. 

What they suggest here http://askubuntu.com/questions/33457/always-be-100-bright-when-im-using-battery  does not work because it is a setting for reducing the brightness after some time of inactivity. 

What I am after is to be able to change brightness with some keys, when the laptop is on AC. This functionality does not exist in my settings manager:

Comment: [url=http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/547/frs.png/][img=http://imageshack.us/scaled/thumb/547/frs.png][/url]

[url=http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/812/t85.png/][img=http://imageshack.us/scaled/thumb/812/t85.png][/url]

Inspired by this solution http://askubuntu.com/questions/79730/how-can-i-adjust-brightness-settings-when-i-am-on-battery I thought that perhaps it could work in my case as  well - to  set two scripts which will increment / decrement  the value stored in /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness, and then

Comment: associate execution of those scripts with some keys using Settings Editor. However I am not fluent with those scripts - does anyone know how it would look like to perform an increment of 0.1 in the value of that file? 

I tried to check how it should look like, but at the moment it does not even allow me to manually tweak the brightness. After permission problems

Comment: `sudo echo 0.8 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` 
`bash: /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness: Permission denied`I changed permission of brightness file, to read

`ls -al  /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/`
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Jul  6 14:52 brightness


But the command 

`sudo echo 0.8 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`
results in  `echo: write error: Invalid argument`

So how should I change the value of that file? It seems that what worked for them in that script, might not work for me... 


Best wishes,

Chris